# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Invalid credentials for relay

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

At our office others can use the .NET SMTP client to send email via our Google Apps account.  Using the exact same settings and credentials this does not work on a particular machine.  It seems to be just this one machine with this issue.  I get:

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Invalid credentials for relay
```

We are all on the same external IP, so it's not

Comment: See if this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717743/mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-5-7-1-unable-to-relay-error

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  We found the smoking gun.  Here is what the message actually says:

> SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1
>   Invalid credentials for relay [ffff:fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff]

I've obfuscated the last part, but note that the IP address this appears to come from is an IPV6 address.  Out relay whitelist only includes IPV4 addresses.  So I turned IPV6 off on that machine - because honestly, what is that good for anyway?